# How to split mono signal to sterio siginal of AD9833 Sin wave generator?

Tags: amplifier, signal-processing, function-generator

I am sorry that I am not well aware in audio amplifiers, that's why I am asking this question maybe it's my stupidity. I have an AD9833 sin wave generator, I need to connect the AD9833's output to TPA6100 Low power stereo headphone amplifier.I am confused about how I use the mono signal coming from AD9833 to the TPA6100 because it is a stereo amplifier. If anyone can help me.

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Just connect the generator's output in parallel to each of the amplifier's inputs.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk0UZj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Connection diagram.*

This assumes that the sine out signal voltage level is correct for your audio amplifier.